# In the Controller of the MVC3 in the Edit Result Data not being passed back to the View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, edit

I created a dropdownlist that passes that data fine. However when I want to edit the form the old values in the GET operation wont populate in the Form. I am new to MVC so a concise example would be great.  Update - I think I know whats going on and need help solving. The ddl only contains my dropdown data, so I am passing only the dropdown data to the Model in the Edit View. The data for the form is in the variable model below in my code , how can I pass the ddl and the model in the View?

HERES MY CODE IN THE CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var ddl = new Users();
            ddl.DropDowns = userRepository.Getddl("Departments").Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = c.DropdownID.ToString(),
                Text = c.DropdownText
            });
                        var model = userRepository.GetUserId(id);
            return View(ddl);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Models.Users users)
        {
            userRepository.UpdateUser(users);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

VIEW

```
@model Models.Users

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div id="stylized" class="myform">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>User Account</legend>     

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserFullName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserFullName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserFullName)
        </div>
       <br/>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <br/>
         <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProfileName)
        </div>
          <div class="editor-field">
       @Html.DropDownListFor(x=> x.DeptID,new SelectList(Model.DropDowns,"Value","Text"),"Select")      

        </div>
```

Comment: Which old values are you referring to? The userid stuff?

Comment: When you look at the details of data in a form and then click edit, I want those details to show so the user can edit the form. I get a blank form instead. In the details the data is in the model.

Comment: please exaplin little more ? which view /action you are expecting the data to come ? and what data ?how does your view looks like

Comment: When I am in the detail View, I click on the Edit Action. There is data already in the form in the detail View. It worked when I passed the model, but I made some dropdownlist that I had to pass to the view. So I guess the problem is I am not passing the model but only the dropdown data. Ill post my View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a wrong object to your view. Pass the user obeject which you get from your Repositary method. Assuming your `GetUserID` method returns an object of `User` class and it has a  `DropDowns` property in your user object

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id)
 {
     var model = userRepository.GetUserId(id);
     model.DropDowns = userRepository.Getddl("Departments").
                                          Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.DropdownID.ToString(),
            Text = c.DropdownText
        });                      
     return View(model);
 }
```

Comment: Hi Shyju,  After I click on the Edit button in the Detail View, I come to a Blank Form...I want the data to persist in that form. My Httppost works fine.

Answer (score 1):

you're passing a new (empty) `User` to the view. You want to pass the model to the view instead.

```
return View(model);
```

Comment: Correct....but how do I pass the model and the ddl. In other words how would I add ddl to the model to pass.

Comment: Create a view model that has all the properties you need.  Populate it in your controller action and pass it to the view.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, your edit view isn't showing the User data. Instead it is showing a blank form as if it were a "new" action?

I think you are passing the wrong model through to your view - you should be passing model, but you are passing ddl - (ddl is a new user).

You can pass your drop down through the viewbag, or alternatively, create a view model that will contain your user as well as a drop down list

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the model and the DropDownList into the view. The primary object should be the model because that's what your view is based from. However, since you also need to get the DropDownList into the view as well, you can either attach it to the model or add it through the ViewBag:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
   var ddl = new Users();
   ddl.DropDowns = userRepository.Getddl("Departments").Select(c => new SelectListItem
   {
       Value = c.DropdownID.ToString(),
       Text = c.DropdownText
   });

   var model = userRepository.GetUserId(id);

   // When accessing this from the view, you will
   // call it by ViewBag.DepartmentsDropdown
   ViewBag.DepartmentsDropdown = dll;

   return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Heres how I get the DropDown in my edit View.  @Html.DropDownListFor(x=> x.DeptID,new SelectList(Model.DropDowns,"Value","Text"),"Select") .  So I would replace that with  ViewBag.DepartmentsDropdown?

Comment: @StoneTempleAviators: The view is for editing a user I would think (based on context), so the model should be about the user rather than what's in the dropdown. So, yes, unless you want to place your dropdown into your model, you'd need to change it to ViewBag.DepartmentsDropdown.

Comment: Well I did it Like this: @Html.DropDownListFor(x=> x.DeptID,new SelectList(@ViewBag.DepartmentsDropdown,"Value","Text"),"Select") and that didnt work. So I just did a plain @ViewBag.DeparmentDropdown and it displayed .. Model.Users on my page.

Answer (score 0):

Create eg. UsersViewModel class, add properties like SelectList to feed dropdown, list of users and all other data which you would like pass into view.
Before returning view initialize instance of this class, set properties and pass it as a model.

```
..
var model = new UsersViewModel
{
   Users = new SelectList(..),
   ...
}
return View(model);
```

Then in your view you can refer to all object coming from that ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , thanks to everyone input I was able to solve it. I didnt want to recreate the model that I had. The reason I wasnt seeing the Data was because I wasnt passing the model. So i have to create ViewData to hold my dropdown information. In hindsight it would be better to spend more time on the model so I dont run into issues like this. Without everyones help I would not have gotten this.

In the Controller

```
ViewData["DepartmentDD"] = new SelectList(ddl.DropDowns, "Value", "Text");
```

In the View

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DeptID, (SelectList)ViewData["DepartmentDD"], "Choose one")